# Ajax requests in phonegap projects on android

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, dojo, cordova

My dojo based project worked fine with phonegap 2.7.0 but after "upgrade" with phonegap 3.0 none of the ajax requests seem to be getting through.

I created a simple test page with plain javascript (to eliminate dojo as a variable) and the results are the same.

Thanks
Mike

My environment

1. phonegap 3.0
2. Android 4.1.1 on Galaxy S3, or Android 4.3 on emulator
3. The < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> is present in the manifest
4. < access origin="*" /> is present in the config.xml

javascript:

```
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      alert ("rdystate: " + xmlhttp.readyState);
      alert ("status: "   + xmlhttp.status);
      alert ("Text: "     + xmlhttp.statusText);
      alert ("ResponseText: " + xmlhttp.responseText);
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://10.0.2.2:8080/myapp/rest/feedback/ping",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

output:

```
    rdystate: 1
    rdystate: 2
    status: 404
    Text: *empty*
    ResponseText: *empty*
    rdystate: 4
    status: 404
    Text: *empty*
    ResponseText: *empty*
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about this but I believe that using IP addresses may *not* fall under the domain whitelist? Can you point a DNS record to it and try using the domain name instead?